# API : Http failure during parsing after calling HttpGet

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api, saml, sustainsys-saml2

I am trying to add SSO to my application but I am getting the error below. We are using ASPNETZero template & Azure Active Directory as a external login provider.

```
error: Object { error: SyntaxError, text: "\r\n\r\n<!-- Copyright (C) Microsoft Corporation. All rights reserved. -->\r\n<!DOCTYPE html>\r\n<html dir=\"ltr\" class=\"\" lang=\"en\">\r\n<head>\r\n    <title>Sign in to your account</title>\r\n    <meta http-equiv=\"Content-Type\" content=\"text/html; charset=UTF-8\">\r\n    <meta http-equiv=\"X-UA-Compatible\" content=\"IE=edge\">\r\n    <meta name=\"viewport\" content=\"width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=2.0, user-scalable=yes\">\r\n    <meta http-equiv=\"Pragma\" content=\"no-cache\">\r\n    <meta http-equiv=\"Expires\" content=\"-1\">\r\n    <link rel=\"preconnect\" href=\"https://aadcdn.msauth.net\" crossorigin>\r\n<meta http-equiv=\"x-dns-prefetch-control\" content=\"on\">\r\n<link rel=\"dns-prefetch\" href=\"//aadcdn.msauth.net\">\r\n<link rel=\"dns-prefetch\" href=\"//aadcdn.msftauth.net\">\r\n\r\n    <meta name=\"PageID\" content=\"ConvergedSignIn\" />\r\n    <meta name=\"SiteID\" content=\"\" />\r\n    <meta name=\"ReqLC\" content=\"1033\" />\r\n    <meta name=\"LocLC\" content=\"en-US\" />\r\n\r\n\r\n    <noscript>\r\n        <meta http-equiv=\"Refresh\" con…" }
​
headers: Object { normalizedNames: Map(0), lazyUpdate: null, lazyInit: lazyInit()
 }
​
message: "Http failure during parsing for https://login.microsoftonline.com/86e6a21f-c39e-43e1-b65c-caa4cea07c6c/saml2?SAMLRequest=fZLBbtswEER%2FReCdFkXJkkPYBty4RQWkrRC7OeRS0MwyJkCRKpdy078vLTtFemiui53ZeUMuUfZ2EJsxHt09%2FBwBY9ZuV%2BSH1ofmwEtG51JLWjUNULngnLKG14tC66bRQLIHCGi8WxE%2BYyRrEUdoHUbpYhoxzigrKCv3BRfzSrDqkWTbdME4GSfVMcYBRZ5b%2F2zcrDcqePQ6emeNg5nyfb6ooZa80FSVN0CrEgp6qOeKKikrBZI1qlb5mYGT7JMPCiaSFdHSYsrXYicRzQn%2BTrrgo1fefjDuybjnFRmDE16iQeFkDyiiErvNlzuRiMThsoTi837f0e7bbk%2ByDSKEc%2Fxb73DsIewgnIyC7%2Fd3b4GUtEePUVRVeVPlcjD52TX%2Fn5pkL711KKbneD%2FUcCUg6%2BV5W0ythzf69%2BWpj0sCsn5N%2B%2FFF9oOFa5TU0Mk8QVhOvV7tL7cG8TX5tdvOW6N%2BZxtr%2Fa%2FbADKmfmMYE0W%2Bvsj%2B%2FVLrPw%3D%3D&RelayState=http%3A%2F%2Flocalhost%3A4200"
​
name: "HttpErrorResponse"
​
ok: false
​
status: 200
​
statusText: "OK"
​
url: "https://login.microsoftonline.com/86e6a21f-c39e-43e1-b65c-caa4cea07c6c/saml2?SAMLRequest=fZLBbtswEER%2FReCdFkXJkkPYBty4RQWkrRC7OeRS0MwyJkCRKpdy078vLTtFemiui53ZeUMuUfZ2EJsxHt09%2FBwBY9ZuV%2BSH1ofmwEtG51JLWjUNULngnLKG14tC66bRQLIHCGi8WxE%2BYyRrEUdoHUbpYhoxzigrKCv3BRfzSrDqkWTbdME4GSfVMcYBRZ5b%2F2zcrDcqePQ6emeNg5nyfb6ooZa80FSVN0CrEgp6qOeKKikrBZI1qlb5mYGT7JMPCiaSFdHSYsrXYicRzQn%2BTrrgo1fefjDuybjnFRmDE16iQeFkDyiiErvNlzuRiMThsoTi837f0e7bbk%2ByDSKEc%2Fxb73DsIewgnIyC7%2Fd3b4GUtEePUVRVeVPlcjD52TX%2Fn5pkL711KKbneD%2FUcCUg6%2BV5W0ythzf69%2BWpj0sCsn5N%2B%2FFF9oOFa5TU0Mk8QVhOvV7tL7cG8TX5tdvOW6N%2BZxtr%2Fa%2FbADKmfmMYE0W%2Bvsj%2B%2FVLrPw%3D%3D&RelayState=http%3A%2F%2Flocalhost%3A4200"
```

Angular code:

```js
this._httpClient
            .get<any>('https://localhost:44394/api/Saml/InitiateSingleSignOn?returnUrl=http://localhost:4200', {
                headers: {
                    'Access-Control-Allow-Origin': '*',
                    'Access-Control-Allow-Methods': 'GET,POST',
                    'Access-Control-Allow-Headers': '*',
                    'content-type': 'text/html'
                }
            })
            .subscribe(response => {
                console.log('Result : ' + response.result);
            });
```

API Code:

```cs
[HttpGet]
public async Task<IActionResult> InitiateSingleLogout(string returnUrl = null)
{
  // Request logout at the identity provider.
  await _samlServiceProvider.InitiateSloAsync(relayState: returnUrl);

  // Redirect to the target URL if specified.
  if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(returnUrl))
  {
    return Redirect(returnUrl);
  }

   return new EmptyResult();
}
```

Comment: Setting the `access-control-allow-...` headers in a *request* does nothing.  Those are response headers set by the target system.  Also, CORS doesn't apply to server-side code at all.

Comment: Thanks, @Amy... The issue has been resolved. This has occurred because in this the SAML is a browser-based protocol & in response, we get HTML forms &  it has javascript code to auto-submit this form. So it will not be working with API.